# Start the first terminal from tmux

Tags: tmux

I usually start my second terminal from tmux by a cumbersome steps

1) Start a terminal ( I used alacritty)
2) initiate a tmux session `tmux new -s 'main'`
3) start a second terminal `alacritty`

The I closed the first terminal and work on the second one.

The steps is clumsy, since the first terminal invoked only as  an intermediate.

How could start the first terminal(alacritty) directly from tmux?

Comment: Please delete your [first question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1146897/354663) before you ask it again.

Comment: okay, deleted it, ty @danzel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alacritty` is a terminal emulator. It's the drawing on your GUI that lets you do thing as if you were on the console.

`tmux` is a terminal multiplexer like `screen` that lets you run multiple terminal sessions within a single terminal but that can remain active even if you end your terminal application or connection.

You can connect to `tmux` from within `alacritty` or any other terminal emulator or ssh, etc connection. You can even connect to the same session from multiple terminals.

1. Start `alacritty` however you start it.
2. Type `tmux attach || tmux new` to attach to an existing session or start a new one.
3. Use `tmux attach -t target-name || tmux new -s target-name` to attach or create to a specific session.

Alternatively a script file:

~/bin/tmuxed:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux attach -t MyFavSession || tmux new -s MyFavSession
```

Create a shortcut or edit the Alacritty menu entry to...

```
alacritty -e $HOME/bin/tmuxed
```

...to start alacritty with the tmux attach/new command automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

I went into my `~/.alacritty.yml` file and set my default shell to run with the argument `tmux`:

```
shell:

  program: /bin/fish

  args:

    - --login

    - -c tmux
```

[screenshot of my .alacritty.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7YS.png)